# setState not changes value inside setTimout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a state (**page**) which I want to change everytime some buttons clicked. Page's value doesn't change although **setPage** gets called each time.

Code is clear:

```js
const [page, setPage] = useState<number>(1);

useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((e) => {
        e.addEventListener("click", () => {
            setPage(parseInt(e.textContent ?? "1")); // this line executes but page value doesn't change
            setTimeout(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                // irrelevant code
                }, 10);
            }, 200);
        });
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value

Comment: As a general rule, don't manually attach event listeners or use timeouts/intervals with React (Both can cause issues with the asynchronous re-rendering nature of React) What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Handle event listeners in react this way: https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events

Comment: Could this be a stale closure issue? Read more about it here: https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/

Comment: @Pavindu Thank you I totaly forgot how to handle cicks

Answer (score 0):

Since the dependency array of your `useEffect()` is an empty array, it never evaluates more than once with the initial value of `page`.  You would need to add `page` to the dependency array, but that will introduce another issue because you will be adding new event listeners every time the value of `page` changes.  To handle that, you would need add a clean-up function returned by the `useEffect()` which removes the existing event listeners:

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

// A reference to the function we want to add and remove
const clickHandler = () => {
    setPage(parseInt(e.textContent ?? "1")); // this line executes but page value doesn't change
    setTimeout(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
        // irrelevant code
        }, 10);
    }, 200);
}

useEffect(() => {
    // Every time `page` changes, set events up with the new value of `page`
    document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((e) => {
        e.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
    });
    return () => {
        // Clean up the existing event listeners using the old value of `page`
        document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((e) => {
            e.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);
        });
    }
}, [page]);
```

As others have mentioned, this code is still an anti-pattern because you are bailing out of React (via the useEffect) to directly add event listeners on the DOM.  [You might not need an Effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect).